# pthread cleanup function is not getting called when try catch block is being used

Tags: c++

Can somebody tell me why the cleanup function is not getting called for the below code. It is always generating an exception upon calling pthread_cancel function which I was not expecting. This is my sample code below

```
void threadCleaner(void* t)
{
    printf("%s\n",__func__);
}

void* thread(void* t)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(threadCleaner,NULL);
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            pthread_test_cancel();
            //recvfrom socket function
            ...
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            printf("exception in %s\n",__func__);
        }
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t,NULL,thread,NULL);

    while(true)
    {
        char a[10];
        fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
        if(strncasecmp(a,"exit",4)==0)
            break;
    }

    pthread_cancel(t);
    pthread_join(t,NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

I am running this code on gcc compiler 4.1.2

Comment: error: cannot convert '_IO_FILE*' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)'
         fgets(stdin,a,sizeof(a));

Comment: @lars I have corrected my question